# I need some help for my website

Tags: button, navigation, web, weebly

i'm new to this website, so this is my first post!

Anyways, I came to ask something about a website i'm making for my Webcomic(i'm using Weebly, BTW). how can you be able to us the buttons when wanting to see another page of a comic.

And i'm talking about navigation buttons, BTW. Not to mention that Weebly can only allow me to use 10 pages until I can upgrade. :p

So yeah, that's all I have for now, I hope you can help. Please and Thank you.

Comment: I found this online, I think it talks about Weebly. http://www.weebly.com

Answer (score 0):

With the 10 page limit I think your best option may be adding a slideshow or gallery if you want to remain a free user.

http://kb.weebly.com/slideshow.html

http://kb.weebly.com/image-gallery.html

Comment: You could also try to get really tricky with blog posts linking to the previous and next post but that would take a lot of effort.